# Angular 4: Access to XMLHttpRequest has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, cors

Trying to get the data from PHP Api to Angular 4

**Component.ts:**

```
this.usraeem_ser.get_error_msg(JSON.stringify(this.colFilter)).subscribe(
      (errMsg : any) => {
        console.log(errMsg);
      },
      (error: any) => console.log (error["message"])
    );
```

this.colFilter is the array of objects.

**Services.ts:**

```
get_error_msg(errObj : any):Observable<any>{

    return this.http.post(this.error_msg,errObj,{
      headers: new HttpHeaders ({
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      })
    })

  }
```

this.error_msg is the path of API

**In php file:**

```
<?php 

    // required headers
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
echo json_encode("test");
?>
```

Even after giving Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * in backend API I'm getting following error:

[image]

What is wrong I'm doing any solution or any alternative way to do this.

Comment: On the first view it seems good. Which browser did you use?

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Canary browser](https://www.google.com/chrome/canary/) or the below command.

Strictly suggested for development.

```
chromium-browser --disable-web-security --user-data-dir="[some directory here]"
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem lies in

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
```

You are allowing only "access" header. Where as Angular would set around 4 or 5 default headers.

Here, you can provide wildcard * or mention the headers that are allowed. Like

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization");
```

or

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```